# Media queries seem to be ignored, even with viewport declaration

Tags: css, media-queries, viewport

the tablet/phone media query styles that I have set on [my site](http://wssymphony.org) seem to be ignored, even though I have a viewport declaration in the `<head>` and the `@media` styles are at the bottom of the stylesheet—so they can't be over-ridden by desktop styles.  I'm sure it's something very simple, but I've tried everything that I can think of. The styles are ignored both on mobile and on desktop when the browser window is resized.  Oddly enough, the responsive menu works fine...but the rest of the site is riddled with uncomfortable padding, floats, and margins without the mobile styles.  Any help is appreciated!

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768 px){      
body {     }          
#container {padding: 0;}          
#content, #content-archive, #content-full, #content-blog, #content-images, #content-sitemap {padding: 0px;}         #content h2, #content-full h2, #content-blog h2 {margin-left: 0px;}          
#header { padding: 0.5em;       overflow:auto; }               
#header #logo img {max-width: 100%;}                  
.archive #widgets, .page #widgets {width:100%;padding 20px;}      
.grid, .grid-right {float:none;}        
#scaleContainer {display: none;}        
#mobilefeatured {display:block;     width: 100%; margin-top:17.5%;          zoom:58%;}      
#mobilecarousel-hype-container { max-width: 100%; }         
.page .featuredimg {display:block;  } 
.archive .featuredimg, .single .featuredimg, .search .featuredimg {display:block; }         
.top-menu {display:none;}       
.top-menu li a, .top-menu li:first-child a {        }       
.menu li, .footer-menu li, .sub-header-menu li {float:none;text-align:left; }      
.page .menu-item-6820, .single .menu-item-6820 { display:none;  }       
#mobile-nav-instruct {display: none;}    #search {float:none;  text-align: left;  margin:auto;}         
#search input[type="text"] {text-align: left;}      
#wrapper {clear:none; position:relative;} 
.post-entry {padding: 20px; }    
.post-entry h1, .post-entry h2, .post-entry h3, .post-entry h6, .post-entry div h1, .post-entry div h2, .post-entry div h3, .post-entry div h6, .entry h2 {         padding-left: 0;    }       
.post-entry h6, .post-entry div h6 {margin-bottom: 10px;    }    
.summary {width:100%; margin:0;     } 
.thumbnail-wrapper {width: 100%;        height:auto;}          
.summary img {max-width:100%;       height:auto; }          
.summary h2 {width:100%; margin: 10px auto;}    
.dates-artists {width:100%;         margin:0;}      
.rep {width:100%; margin:0;     }       #photo-rep {float:none; width: 100%;}   
#vitals {float:left; clear: both; width: 100%;  margin-left: 0px;  margin-top:20px;  -webkit-border-radius:0px;         -moz-border-radius:0px; background-color:#fff; border: none; border-radius:0px; font-size: 100%; padding: 5px 0px !important; }             
.info-buy {     }       
.programPricing { clear:both;       padding-left:0px;  margin-top:-20px;  margin-left:0; }   
#share .dates, .buy-dates-wrapper .dates { padding-left: 2em; width:75%;  line-height: 1.5em;} 
.home .widget-wrapper { height: auto; padding: 1em;     border:none;        background-color: #fff; font-size: 14px; }      
.desc {float:right; clear:none;}
.home .newsblog {height: auto;      padding: 1em; border:none;      background-color: #fff; font-size: 14px;    }       
.widget-wrapper { background-color:#fff; border:none; font-size:14px; height: auto; padding: 1em;}      
.bio { width:100%;  }   
.roster { width:100%; }         #googleCalEmbed { display: none; }   #googleEmbedLink {display:block;}   #seating table { border: none; width:100%; margin:0%;}         
#seating td {border: none;}
#seatingMobileHint {display:block;}
.sponsors { clear:both; padding: 0px; text-align:center; -webkit-border-radius:6px; -moz-border-radius:6px; border-radius:6px;  border-top: 1px solid #d6d6d6;} 
.sponsors h6 { margin-top: 1.6em;   } 
.sponsors hr {background:#eee;      border:none; clear:both;        color:#f9f9f9; float:none; height:1px; margin:5px 0px; width:100%;  } 
.sponsors a img.alignnone {         margin:5px 0px; padding:0;float: none;      }    
#footer .footernav {display:none;         }   
#footer {       text-align:left;     }          #footer .widget-wrapper {       padding:0;     }          
#footer h6, h6.title-concertdate {      color:#fff;         padding: 0 8%;          margin-bottom:1em;          text-shadow: none;}          
#mobilecal {        display:block;     }          #mobilecal span.calnk {       opacity: 0;     }   
.home #widgets #cal, .page #widgets, .archive #widgets {        display:block;  }       
.mobilecontact {display:block;}          #footer .social-icons {        text-align:left;     }          
.copyright { text-align: center;    }                           /*    The homepage featured events slider for retina displays     */                
#mobilefeatured {               display:block;  zoom:50%;               } 
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to paste your media queries code on the question

Comment: Huangism: fair enough! See amended question.

Answer (score 1):

Your media query is malformed:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768 px)
```

There must not be a space between the number and the unit:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
```

Comment: That worked! I knew it was something very simple that I overlooked.  Now I can see what I'm tweaking! :)